# Encontrar patrones en un bucle

Tags: python, lista

Os comento, tengo que simular un juego llamado el juego de Penney, el cual consiste en dos jugadores que lanzan una moneda y deben adivinar una secuencia de tres lanzamientos. Por ejemplo, si el jugador A dice que va a salir Cara-Cara-Cara y el jugador B dice Cara-Cruz-Cara, debe lanzarse la moneda hasta que salga una de estas secuencias. Si, por ejemplo, saliera Cruz-**Cara-Cruz-Cara** entonces ganarían el jugador B.

Entonces, debo simular este juego, pero no sé como hacer un Código que reconozca una secuencia dentro de las tiradas de un bucle.

Comment: Usa rebanadas (slices) para recorrer tu secuencia de tiradas, por ejemplo `secuencia[i:i+3]` te dará una rebanada de tres elementos. Compara esa rebanada con una lista preparada de antemano, por ejemplo [0,0,0] o [0,1,0] (si 0 es Cara y 1 es Cruz, o como las hayas representado). Recorriendo en bucle la `i`, cuando tu rebanada coincida con la secuencia preparada lo habrás encontrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te hagas una idea yo lo hice así, suponiendo que, por ejemplo, 0 es cara y 1 es cruz:

```
import random

jugador1 = [0, 1, 1]
jugador2 = [1, 0, 1]

secuencia = []
i = 0
while True:
    tirada = random.randint(0, 1)
    
    secuencia.append(tirada)

    if len(secuencia) < 3:
        continue
    
    if secuencia[i:] == jugador1:
        print("Gano el jugador 1")
        break

    if secuencia[i:] == jugador2:
        print("Gano el jugador 2")
        break

    i += 1
```

El método `randint` del módulo `random` va a generar aleatoriamente 0 o 1. En cada iteración del bucle infinito se comprueban las tres últimas tiradas (con ayuda de la variable contador `i` y cuando ya se han realizado mínimo 3 tiradas) para ver si coincide con las de algún jugador. `secuencia[i:]` serían las tres últimas tiradas.

Ejecutándolo e imprimiendo la secuencia:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
Gano el jugador 2
```

Como se puede ver, el bucle se ha interrumpido cuando ha detectado la secuencia del jugador 2 `[1, 0, 1]`.

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema es que tengo que decir el numero de partidas ganadas por cada jugador, si por ejemplo se hacen 100 partidas, cuantas gana cada jugador, ya que dependiendo de la estrategia de cada jugador, hay más probabilidad de que gane uno u otro. Alguien sabría hacerlo? Gracias!